# Geometry shader

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, qt5

I am trying to add geometry shader to my program. The problem is that I am using QGLfunctions, my OpenGL version is 3.1 and Qt 5.0.

In Qt 5.0 the QOpenGLShader and QOpenGLShaderProgram classes only had support for Vertex andf Fragment shaders. Qt 5.1 includes support for all shader stages supported by OpenGL (including geometry shader). I know how to add shader using addShaderFromSourceCode provided by QGLfunctions but in that way it is not possible to add geometry shader.

Can someone help me how to add geometry shader to my program?

Comment: How did you try to add that? Have you selected the proper type? http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtopengl/qglshader.html#ShaderTypeBit-enum What error did you get when you were trying it?

Comment: You're free to bypass Qt's OpenGL convenience functions and directly load shaders using OpenGL vanilla API.

Answer (score 1):

Don't confound QGL and QOpenGL classes. First was depreciated in Qt 5 and must not be used (just for Qt 4 compatible code). The second don't have geometry shaders in Qt 5.0, only from Qt 5.1 (the reason is Qt 5 was initially based on OpenGL ES for large platform compatibility, support for OpenGL 3-4 was added in Qt 5.1).

You can use classical GL code to use geometry shaders directly (then without Qt)

Comment: What do you mean? There is a geometry shader type. He could use that.

Comment: Yes, there is geometry shader in old (obsolet) QGLShader class or in Qt 5.1's QOpenGLShader class, but not in Qt 5.0's QOpenGLShader.

Comment: I had the impression this should work: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtgui/qopenglshader.html#ShaderTypeBit-enum Yes, I gave the qtopengl link above, but this seems to have that type, too.

Comment: Yes in Qt 5.1. But here, M_global want to use Qt 5.0 and there is no geometry shader support (http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtgui/qopenglshader.html#ShaderTypeBit-enum)

Comment: Ok, I understand your remarks. I add correction in my first message (" not in Qt 5.0, only from Qt 5.1")

Comment: I don't think it's error... waiting his answer to your question

Comment: I can install QT 5.1 but still I need OpenGL >= 3.2, on the other side I want to have portability guaranteed by QGLfunctions. Thats why I try to bypass obsolet QGLShader class

Comment: I installed QT 5.1 and I can use Opengl ES 2.0 subset which is supported by most desktop cards...

Comment: I have difficulties to follows you... If you have Qt 5.1, use QOpenGL classes (idem for GL functions, use QOpenGLFunctions ; and QOpenGLShader propose geometry shaders). For using GL ES 2 or GL > 3, you don't have choice, there is no geometry shaders in GL ES 2.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: you cannot have this feature with Qt 5.0 and OpenGL 3.0.

Make sure you are using Qt 5.1 as the geometry shader support was only added in that version. Qt 5.0 had no such a feature. See the [official documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtgui/qopenglshader.html#ShaderTypeBit-enum) for details.

Also, Sean has [blogged about it](http://www.kdab.com/opengl-in-qt-5-1-part-5/) when they added this feature to Qt.

> QOpenGLShader::Geometry
>
> 0x0004    Geometry shaders written in the OpenGL
> Shading Language (GLSL) based on the OpenGL core feature (requires
> OpenGL >= 3.2).